# how to package several keras layers in one layer-module?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I have to switch from pytorch to keras and in pytorch I can create module-like-layer with code like that:

```
from pytorch import nn

class up(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
    super(up, self).__init__()
    self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)
    self.conv = nn.Conv2D(in_ch, out_ch)
    # !!!! here two layers packaged in one
def forward(self, x1, x2):
    x1 = self.up(x1)
    x = t.cat([x2, x1], dim=1)
    x = self.conv(x)
    return x
```

how to organize code in this kind module-like-layer way in keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured out that one way is to do function:

```
def double_conv(var1, input):
    x = k.layers.Conv2d(some_parameters) (input)
    x = k.layers.Conv2d(some_parameters) (x)
    x = k.layers.MaxPooling2d(some_parameters) (x)
    return x
```

but there is more 'kerasic' way to do it?

---

**EDIT** 
this is what I was looking for to use function like Keras layer but if someone would find better way to organize code then I would welcome any ideas

```
def conv_bn_relu(filters, kernel=(3,3)):
    def inside(x):
        x = Conv2D(filters, kernel, padding='same') (x)
        x = BatchNormalization() (x)
        x = Activation('relu') (x)
        return x
    return inside

# usage:
x = conv_bn_relu(params) (x)
```

---

**EDIT2**
you can even cheat and name this function in CamelCase like classes so it looks like creating Keras like layer

```
def ConvBnRelu(filters, kernel=(3,3)):
    def inside(x):
        x = Conv2D(filters, kernel, padding='same') (x)
        x = BatchNormalization() (x)
        x = Activation('relu') (x)
        return x
    return inside

# usage:
x = ConvBnRelu(params) (x)
```

but probably second solution will be criticized

Comment: Thats pretty much it, though I don't usually see people importing keras as k. Check the networks in applications for some examples. Some of them have predefined blocks which are pretty much modules as you named.

Comment: could you post any particular examples?

Comment: [conv2d_bn](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py#L43) in `applications.inception_v3`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The latest (as of June 2021) [Tensorflow documentation on creating custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers#models_composing_layers) explains how to do that.

TL;DR: either subclass `tf.keras.layers.Layer` or `tf.keras.Model`, the latter being the preferred choice if you want to inspect intermediate results inside the custom block. For example:

```
class ConvolutionalBlock1x1(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, filters):
    super().__init__(name='')

    self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (1, 1))
    self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (1, 1))
    self.conv2c = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (1, 1))

  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2b(x)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2c(x)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)
```